# Insert Ordered Dict values while using MySQL INSERT INTO

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I encounter this error when I'm trying to insert some values into a table.
Here's my code:

```
def tsx_insert(self, d_list):

for item in d_list:

    query = """ INSERT IGNORE INTO tsx_first_insert(protocollo,procedura,oggetto,priorita,
                                                    tipo_richiesta,sottotipo_richiesta,emergenza,
                                                    richiesta,uo_richiedente,autore,scadenza_sla)
                VALUES(%(protocollo)s,%(procedura)s,%(oggetto)s,%(priorita)s,%(tipo_richiesta)s,
                       %(sottotipo_richiesta)s,%(emergenza)s,%(richiesta)s,%(uo_richiedente)s,
                       %(autore)s,%(scadenza_sla)s)"""

    values = item.values()

    self.exec_query(query,values)
```

And here 'exec_query' function:

```
def exec_query(self, query, params):
    try:
        if self.connected is None:
            self.connect()

        self.cursor = self.connected.cursor()
        self.cursor.connection.autocommit(True)
        self.cursor.execute(query)

        if self.cursor.description:
            self.description = [d[0] for d in self.cursor.description]

        self.rows = self.cursor.rowcount
        self.sql_result = self.cursor.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        logging.error('Error {0}: {1}'.format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
    finally:
        self.cursor.close()
```

The error is: "Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%(protocollo)s,%(procedura)s,%(oggetto)s,%(priorita)s,%(tipo_richiesta)s,
      ' at line 4"

I can't figure out what is the problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You left out the most important part of the error

Comment: @e4c5 Edited with full error message

Comment: It doesn't look like you're substituting in the parameters...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention your `params` dictionary in your `self.cursor.execute()` method call, so the parameter strings were left in place rather than substituted.

Try

```
   self.cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: And note that the `values` variable then becomes completely redundant!

Comment: That was a mistake, thank you. However, I got another error:
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) ---> TypeError: format requires a mapping